# Como coclocar uma "galeria" em um modal?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Estou tentando fazer um modal que quando você clica aparece uma galeria de fotos, com duas colunas  mas que fiquem centralizadas e com espaçamento, e também que as imagens fiquem maiores, do jeito que eu fiz ficou assim [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```html
        <button class="btn btn-info centro" type="submit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong3">Saiba mais</button>
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong3" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle3" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle3">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <img class="col-lg-4" src="img/foto.ss1.jpg">
     <img class="col-lg-4" src="img/foto.ss1.jpg">
        <img class="col-lg-4" src="img/foto.ss1.jpg">
        <img class="col-lg-4" src="img/foto.ss1.jpg">
        <img class="col-lg-4" src="img/foto.ss1.jpg">
        <img class="col-lg-4" src="img/foto.ss1.jpg">
        <img class="col-lg-4" src="img/foto.ss1.jpg">
        <img class="col-lg-4" src="img/foto.ss1.jpg">
        <img class="col-lg-4" src="img/foto.ss1.jpg">
        <img class="col-lg-4" src="img/foto.ss1.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você consegue dividir as imagens de 2 em 2 em cada linha com um espaçamento uniforme retirando o padding padrão do body da modal com a classe `.p-0` e adicione uma padding inferior com `.pb-3`:

```
<div class="modal-body p-0 pb-3">
```

Em seguida coloque no seu CSS os estilos e a media rule:

```
#exampleModalLong3 .modal-body img{
   margin: 15px 0 0 15px;
   width: calc(50% - 23px);
   float: left;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 991px) {
   #exampleModalLong3 .modal-body img{
      width: calc(100% - 30px);
   }
}
```

Isso irá dimensionar as imagens de forma uniforme dentro do corpo da modal, com espaçamentos perfeitos. Quando a resolução for menor do que `992px`, cada imagem irá ocupar uma linha inteira dentro da modal (me baseei no `992px` por causa da classe `.col-lg-4` que você usou, mas você pode alterar para a resolução que quiser). Execute o snippet abaixo em tela cheia para melhor visualização:

```css
#exampleModalLong3 .modal-body img{
   margin: 15px 0 0 15px;
   width: calc(50% - 23px);
   float: left;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 991px) {
   #exampleModalLong3 .modal-body img{
      width: calc(100% - 30px);
   }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<button class="btn btn-info centro" type="submit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong3">Saiba mais</button>
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong3" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle3" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle3">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body p-0 pb-3">
        <img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg">
     <img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg">
        <img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg">
        <img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg">
        <img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg">
        <img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg">
        <img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg">
        <img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg">
        <img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg">
        <img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> Não esqueça de retirar as classes `class="col-lg-4"` das imagens.